# String to boolean type conversion problem in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

In my Vue HTML, I have this:

```
<v-textarea auto-grow="true"></v-textarea>
```

It acts correctly, by which I mean that it grows automatically.

However, it throws an error:

```
[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "autoGrow". Expected Boolean, got String with value "true".
```

I would like to get rid of this error instead of just ignoring it because "it's only a warning."

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you dont have to provide a value to auto-grow(presence of auto-grow prop indicates true and absence false). Just having auto-grow is enough. As in
`<v-textarea auto-grow ></v-textarea>`

Comment: Yeah, I might be a Vue noob, but thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Either use

```
<v-textarea :auto-grow="true"></v-textarea>
```

or

```
<v-textarea auto-grow></v-textarea>
```

The first one notifies that you are using a prop with initializing a value.
The second one just notifies you are using a default prop.